# How to plot an error bar plot with standard deviation values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am very new to [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and expect a step-by-step solution. I have data, `series(y)`, which I have to plot against `(x)`. Also I have the standard deviation values for each data point of `(y)`. Now I have to plot these series highlighting the error bars. How can I do that?

The data is in a text file sorted in columns as:

```
X = -50, -49, -48, -47....0....1, 2, 3, 4, 5....till 50

Y = 1.2, 1.0, 1.1, 1.9, 1.3.....
```

Standard deviation `= 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6.....`

Also, how do I control the ticks and appearance property for these kinds of graphs?

Comment: As a side note: For saving/exporting figures, check out the excellent [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) from FileExchange. It saves nice looking figures by default, without having to tweak a bunch of the figure properties yourself.

Answer (score 12):

```
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = sin(x);
e = 0.1 * randn(length(x), 1);

errorbar(x,y,e)

set(gca, 'Xlim', [4 10])
set(gca, 'XTick', 4:2:10)
```

[image]

See also `get(gca)` and `get(gcf)` for other properties to change.

For help on any of these functions, do, for example, `help errorbar`.