# Plotting shaded deviation of a line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization

I would like to plot a line, and in grey-shaded X% deviation of a signal, in MATLAB. Then, I'd plot another signal and see (visually) how much of the second signal is outside the gret-shaded area.

The task I'd like to get help done is the shaded area: similar to the image attached below.

[image]

I am aware of [similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879449/how-to-plot-an-error-bar-plot-with-standard-deviation-values-in-matlab) with `errorbar`, but I think this is a much clearer plot to visualize.

If for example I had:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 1 + sin(x);
```

What would the 5% grey-shaded plot of `y` look like? (that area?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this answer for an example: [MATLAB fill area between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910982/matlab-fill-area-between-lines)

Do you have the error of `y` at each sample in `x`? Let's assume you have and the upper bound is in variable `yu` and the lower bound in variable `yl`. Then you could plot it using:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 1 + sin(x);
% I create some yu and yl here, for the example
yu = y+.1;
yl = y-.1;
fill([x fliplr(x)], [yu fliplr(yl)], [.9 .9 .9], 'linestyle', 'none')
hold all
plot(x,y)
```

`fill(X,Y,ColorSpec,...)` plots a polygon with edges specified in the first two parameters. You have to `fliplr` (flip left-right) the arrays, so that it correctly draws the shape of the area to be filled 'in a circle' around it. The `[.9 .9 .9]` is the colour specification, in this case a light grey. I removed the edge by setting no line, to make it even more similar to your desired plot. One detail: plot the filled area before plotting `y`, because the last plotted object goes on top of the others.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question by editting. I'll take a look at your link, thanks!