# How to plot a scatter plot with error bars indicating standard deviation

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression

I have a set of data Y v/s X (~20k data points) which when plotted are a scatter. I want to plot error bars for Y for a ranges of X(eg. the X axis is of length 100, then I want the errorbars to represent the standard deviation of Y for every 10 units of X)

Comment: Something like that ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879449/how-to-plot-an-error-bar-plot-with-standard-deviation-values-in-matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
N = 100;    % Number of points
n = 10;     % Number of x-bins

% Define and plot points
x = rand(N,1);
y = x.*rand(N,1);
scatter(x, y, '+');

% Define errorbar
bin = linspace(min(x), max(x), n+1);
ind = sum(bsxfun(@minus, x, ones(N,1)*bin)>=0,2);

m = NaN(n,1);
e = NaN(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    m(i) = mean(y(ind==i));   % Mean value over the bin
    e(i) = std(y(ind==i));    % Standard deviation
end

hold on
u = (bin(1:end-1)+bin(2:end))/2;
errorbar(u,m,e,'k');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what i needed. Could you modify the same code for the error plots to indicate a 95% confidence interval and now the x axis is in log. So the error plots would be for every 10 powers.(i.e 2 errorbars for N=100, 3 errorbars for N=1000, etc)

Comment: But for the log spacing, you can simply use the `logspace` instead of the `linspace`: 
    bin = logspace(0, 3, 4);   % Log-spaced binning (1, 10, 100, 1000)

Comment: This is what I meant by 95% confidence interval. I want to make the error bars represent this.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.toolboxfittableparametricdistribution.paramci.html#inputarg_pd 
I have been trying to incorporate this function instead of standard deviation, but have been unsuccessful. (P.S. just started to learn programming, so sorry if I come across as rigid)

Comment: Well, you just have to replace `e(i) = std(...);` by `e(i) = diff(paramci(...))/2;` with the parameters you want. That's quite unrelated to the initial question.

Comment: `e(i) = diff(paramci(...))/2`will not work cause `paramci` function requires a pdf as input. So I did this instead. Does this make sense.

`m = NaN(n,1);
s = NaN(n,1);
e = NaN(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    m(i) = mean(y(ind==i));   % Mean value over the bin
    s(i) = std(y(ind==i));    % Standard deviation
    N = sum(y(ind==i));    % number of responses
    se(i) = s(i)./sqrt(N); %standard error
    e(i) = 1.96*se(i); %95% confidence interval
end`